# Build error in Xamarin missing youtube package

Tags: android, xamarin, youtube

I am getting the following error when trying to build my android xamarin project. I have never ran across this before, and I have no clue how to fix it. Anyone have any ideas? Is there a way to add the dependency? Am I even thinking correctly here?

...Android/obj/Debug/android/src/md548954d6403a7d9a6fe546c5860c66901/BenefitDetailFragment.java(50,50): Error:  error: package com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer does not exist
        com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener,
 (*.Android) javac

Here is my initialization code:

```
    public void OnInitializationFailure(IYouTubePlayerProvider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason)
    {

        if (errorReason.IsUserRecoverableError)
        {
            errorReason.GetErrorDialog(Activity, RECOVERY_REQUEST).Show();
        }
        else
        {
            String error = String.Format("Something went wrong with youtube player.", errorReason.ToString());
            ShowSnackBar(Activity, error, linearMoreInfo, Resource.Color.colorAccent);

        }

    }        

    public void OnInitializationSuccess(IYouTubePlayerProvider p0, IYouTubePlayer player, bool wasRestored)
    {
        mPlayer = player;
        if (!wasRestored)
        {
            player.SetOnFullscreenListener(this);
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(videoId))
            {
                player.CueVideo(videoId);
            }
            else
            {
                player.CueVideo("wKJ9KzGQq0w");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you implement OnInitializedListener ? Can you show the code of what you are doing?

Comment: @YuriS I added the code where I implement the listener

Comment: what package you are using? at what point you get an error? is it compile or runtime? can you show all activity code related to player?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by changing the Build Action of the YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar to EmbeddedJar